# Target Sibling on Hover SCSS without JS?

Tags: css, sass, siblings

I have two divs which are at the same position but **a** has the higher z-index than **b**.

When I hover **a** I want that **b** to change its width for example. Is this possible with CSS/SCSS?

Sorry if this is a duplicate.

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Comment: If B is above A, isn't hovering B the same as hovering A?

Comment: A has the higher z-index so its above B, so you cant hovering B if they have the same dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution in sass, idk if it is the same in css:

```
.a:hover + .b {
  //new width
}
```

Comment: Yes It's native to CSS [**adjacent sibling combinator (+)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)